# Proof of L'Hospital's Rule, Part 2 - Question about inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHvYlrud8j8&ab_channel=AndrewMcCrady and in the proof, he states that when $0 \lt \delta = \min (1, \epsilon, \frac{\epsilon}{|L| + 1}) $,

$(L + \epsilon)(1 - \delta) - \delta \lt \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \lt (L+\epsilon) + \delta$
implies that
$ L - 2 \epsilon \lt \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \lt L + 2 \epsilon $. What I don't understand is how $ L - 2 \epsilon \lt \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} $, and I've tried proving it myself. Can anyone show me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\e{\epsilon}\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}$
By passing terms around,
\begin{align*}
(L+\e)(1-\delta)-\delta\geq L-2\e&\iff L+\e-\delta(L+\e)-\delta\geq L-2\e \abajo
&\iff \delta(L+\e)+\delta\leq 3\e\abajo
&\iff \delta(L+1)+\delta(\e-1)+\delta\leq3\e
\end{align*}
So we need to prove this last inequality. We have
$$
\delta(L+1)+\delta(\e-1)+\delta\leq\delta(|L|+1)+\e+\e\leq3\e.  
$$

Comment: Thank you. But why is it that $-\frac{L+\epsilon}{|L|+1} \gt -1$? Also, shouldn't the fact that $\delta=min(1, \epsilon, \frac{\epsilon}{|L|+1})$ imply that $\delta \le 1, \epsilon, \frac{\epsilon}{|L|+1}$ rather than strict inequality?

Comment: You are right. Take a look at the new argument. I prefer to write inequalities directly, without going through equivalences, but I didn't have time for more than this.

Comment: I think I was meant to put $L - \epsilon$ instead of $L + \epsilon$ at the left side of the equation, and so did the person who made the video. But I was able to figure it out. Thanks for your help.